# Populate input field value inside of a for loop on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, event-handling, user-input

I created an app that uses several Google Maps APIs to return the distance and trip time between start address and destination address fields. When I initially created this, I tested by grabbing values from the variable `addresses` value which is an array of 15 service address locations I pulled from a database query for my company. Inside of my for loop, I populated the start address (startaddress[i]) and the destination address (destaddress[i+1]) dynamically. Here's a screenshot of how it worked when I tested initially. I covered up the actual addresses, but it did work as intended here.

[image: Original call inside of the for loop]

After testing this I created a form that takes either an address or zip code value that the user enters into an input field (at the top of the page), which I would like to populate the `#destaddress` (Destination Address or second address field) for each input field labeled "Destination Address". The user can enter either of these values and I would like to populate each `destaddress` inside of my for loop with the user input value. I tried populating this inside of the for loop just before the `getDistance` function, where I set `destInput.value = patientAddress.value`, but nothing happens when I enter the value and submit the form with the setPatientAddress function.

My question is, how can I get the destination address to populate with what is entered in the top input from my html form `#patientaddress` via this form?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Service Center - Google Maps Distance Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-lg" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <form id="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Destination</span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Zip or Full Address" id="patientaddress">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-2" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <p id="log"></p>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&key=[GoogleMapsAPIkey]"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
let startInput, destInput;
// Set headers
const headers = {
    'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'xxxxxxxx.quickbase.com',
    'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

// Call QB table and pull data from column facID 6, address 8
const body = {
    "from": "xxxxxxxx",
    "select": [6, 8],
    "options": {
        "skip": 0,
        "top": 0
    }
}


function generateHTML() {
    // Create xml request class
    const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open('POST', 'https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', true);
    // Extract keys from headers
    for (const key in headers) {
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            const jsonObject = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
            const facId = jsonObject.data.map(e => e["6"].value);
            const addresses = jsonObject.data.map(e => e["8"].value);
            // Grab container div entry point in html
            const container = document.querySelector(".container-lg");
            // const patientAddress = document.querySelector("#patientaddress");
            const form = document.querySelector("#form");
            const patientAddress = document.querySelector("#patientaddress");



            // Create html elements dynamically based on length of addresses array
            for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
                let div = document.createElement("div");
                div.classList.add("card", "card-body", "mb-3");
                div.innerHTML = `<div class="mx-auto" style="width: 800px; margin-top: 25px;">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Service Center: ${facId[i]}</h5>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Starting Address</span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" readonly type="text" placeholder="Start Address" id="startaddress${i}">
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Destination</span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Zip or Full Address" id="destaddress${i}">
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Distance <span id="distance${i}"></span></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Trip Time <span id="time${i}"></span></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
                container.appendChild(div);
                // Dynamically set and number input fields
                startInput = document.querySelector(`#startaddress${[i]}`);
                startInput.value = addresses[i];
                destInput = document.querySelector(`#destaddress${[i]}`);
                // destInput.value = patientAddress.value;

                function setPatientAddress(e) {
                    destInput.value = patientAddress.value;
                    console.log(destInput.value);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

                // destInput.value = destinationAddresses[0];

                function getDistance() {

                    // Create Google Maps distance matrix class
                    const distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                    // Add matrix settings
                    distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
                            // Origins and destinations must be called inside of the for loop
                            origins: [startInput.value],
                            destinations: [destInput.value],
                            travelMode: "DRIVING",
                            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                            durationInTraffic: true,
                            avoidHighways: false,
                            avoidTolls: false
                        },

                        // Set catch, try
                        function(response, status) {
                            if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                                console.log('Error:', status);
                            } else {
                                // console.log(response);
                                destInput.value = patientAddress.value;
                                document.getElementById(`distance${[i]}`).innerHTML = `${response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text}`;
                                document.getElementById(`time${[i]}`).innerHTML = `${response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text}`;
                            }
                        });
                }

                // Register Focus out Listener on Input Fields so we calculate distance and Time
                startInput.addEventListener("focusout", getDistance);
                destInput.addEventListener("focusout", getDistance);
                form.addEventListener('submit', setPatientAddress);
                // getDistance();
                // end for loop
            }
        }
    };

    // Send body request object to Quick Base via RESTful API
    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(body));
}

// Call The generateHTML Function when the page is ready
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', generateHTML);
```

If I console log the value of `destInput` after assigning it the value of `patientAddress` inside of the function `setPatientAddress`, I can see that the value shows up 15 times inside of the for loop, but the value of the input fields for `destInput` are not populating. I'm not exactly sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

I removed

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', generateHTML);
```

at the very end of my JavaScript code. I then added a global variable named `inputVal` and gave it the value of an empty string.

At the very end of the code outside after my `generateHTML` function I added

```
const form = document.querySelector("#form");
const patientAddressValue = document.querySelector("#patientaddress");
const destiInput = document.querySelector(".destInput");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    inputVal = patientAddressValue.value;
    console.log(inputVal);
    // Call The generateHTML function only after the user enters a value
    generateHTML();
});
```

This function allowed me to set `inputVal` to the value entered by the user and assign it to the value of `patientAddressValue`.value. after removing the listener that fired the `generateHTML` function, I was able to call it inside of this new function.

At the moment, I can only capture the first part of the string, so if I add an address, say, 910 Diamond St, San Diego, CA 92109, I am only passing the 910 so I am still working through this unless someone can help me figure out this part as well. I can, however, enter the zip which triggers the functionality I would like as well.